# PHP mail function issue with headers

Tags: php, email, php-5.5, email-headers

```
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <coin2bid@example.com>' . "\r\n"; 
    $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
if( $retval == true ) {
echo 1;
} else 
{echo 0; 
}
```

I am trying to execute the above code. Few months ago i used the same on some another server.It was working perfectly. But now i am trying to execute it on some anopther server.But not working.Please suggest me some solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you define "not working"? Are you getting an error? Is the email being filtered by spam filters?

Comment: Thanks for reply..getting 0 as output

Comment: yeah we know it is 0. because it returns false. Have you checked your logs? something should be there

Comment: What does your mail server's logs show?

Comment: Where are your message and subject variables?

Comment: my logs folder is empty. Could you please tell me how to check it via ftp.cause i dont have cpanel access

Comment: I giving values to that variables: $to,$message,$subject.